# Correlation with stratified data structure

Tags: correlation, multilevel-analysis, similarities, stratification

I have a dataset with two stratas, the first level is called block, which represents the census block. the second level is two predetermined subgroups in each blocks, each subgroup contains several households.

```
     block  subgroup    id
       1        1       1
       1        1       2
       1        1       3
       ·······
       3        1       5
       3        2       1
       3        2       2
       3        2       3
```

Now what I want is to measure the similarity between individuals in different stratas. Specificly, I first randomly draw a household from ***subgroup 1*** in each block, in the first step, I calculate the average value of a certain individual characteristics (say, income) of the ***rest*** individuals in the block (denote `ave_income1`), and calculate the correlations between the selected individual's income (denoted `sel_income1`) and `ave_income1`, denoted as `corr_income1`. Next, I do the same job in the subgroup level, `ave_income2` denotes the average value of individual income in ***subgroup2***, and calculate the `corr_income2`. Then I compare `corr_income1` and `corr_income2` to see if there is significant difference so that I can check if the households in two groups are fundamentally different in some sense.

So I wonder if my method descripted here is defensible for my purpose，especially the averging part? And should I re-draw many times to make my result more robust? I don't know if there is some well-built theory on this context for I'm just a reg monkey, if it indeed existed, please throw some links or papers or tutorials for me, thanks your guys.